# What does get() do when assigning value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variable-assignment

The code here is assigning the _showProgress to showProgress by using the get()

```
private val _showProgress = MutableLiveData<SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>>()
override val showProgress : LiveData<SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>>
    get() = _showProgress
```

The code here is the same as above and it seems like there is no difference when running the code, it does the same job as above. What does the `get()` in the above code do? Is it necessary to use the `get()` when assigning the value?

```
private val _showProgress = MutableLiveData<SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>>()
override val showProgress : LiveData<SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>> = _showProgress
```

Comment: It's an [accessor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/-accessor/index.html) with a backing field. See also https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Strictly speaking, it's an accessor _without_ a backing field. `_showProgress` is a property (which does have its own backing field), not a field.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah I see, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method doesn't change the value — but it does change the *type*.  (The static, compile-time type, anyway.)

The private property is a `MutableLiveData` field.  I don't know that type, but it looks like a class or interface which wraps some data (in this case a `SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>`), and allows it to be changed.

The public property, though, is a `LiveData`.  That's probably a superclass or superinterface of `MutableLiveData` which lacks the method(s) allowing the data to be changed.  The overridden getter method simply returns the value of the private property, but in doing so upcasts it to the non-mutable type.

The result is that code within the class can access the mutable field, which other code can only get a read-only view of it.  So it's effectively doing some encapsulation, restricting the ability to change the field while still allowing it to be seen.

(You wouldn't need to call the getter explicitly; simply using the property syntax `myObject.showProgress` will call the getter for you.  In Kotlin,  all properties get a getter method -- and, if `var` a setter; you only need to override the default ones if you want different behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit to gidds' answer and focusing specifically on comparison with

```
override val showProgress : LiveData<SingleLiveEventWrapper<Boolean>> = _showProgress
```

If you use `= ...` without an explicit getter, a backing field is created and `_showProgress` is stored there while constructing the object. So there are two fields storing the same value. In this case this shouldn't make any difference beyond using a bit more memory, but in other cases it could:

1. if `_showProgress` was a `var` it could be reassigned after construction. Then if `showProgress` is defined with `get()`, accessing it will always get the current value of `_showProgress`, but without `get()` it'll get the initial one.
2. Similarly if `_showProgress` was `open protected` and overridden in a subclass (due to initialization order).